# How should I call parent move constructor in diamond pattern?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-semantics, diamond-problem

Consider following diamond-like multiple inheritance:

```
class base;
class d1 : virtual public base;
class d2 : virtual public base
class d3 : public d1, public d2;
```

`base` is a move-only class (having a large move-only buffer). So are `d1`, `d2` and `d3`. Move constructor of `d1` and `d2` call move constructor of the `base`.

Then what should do move constructor of `d3`? Calling both move-ctors of d1 and d2 results in crashs (since move constructor of `base` is called twice.

Here I have a minimum compilable instance of the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

struct moveonly {
    moveonly(): data(nullptr) {}
    moveonly(const moveonly &) = delete;
    moveonly(moveonly &&other) {
        this->data = other.data;
        other.data = nullptr;
    }
    ~moveonly() {
        if(data)
            delete[] data;
    }
    char *data;
};

class base {
    public:
        base() = default;
        base(const base &) = delete;
        base(base &&other) : d(std::move(other.d)) {  }
        virtual ~base() = default;
        int a;
        int b;
        moveonly d;
};

class d1 : virtual public base {
    public:
        d1() = default;
        d1(const base &) = delete;
        d1(d1 &&other) : base(std::move(other)) {  }
        int x;
        int y;
};

class d2 : virtual public base {
    public:
        d2() = default;
        d2(const base &) = delete;
        d2(d2 &&other) : base(std::move(other)) {  }
        int r;
        int s;
};

class d3 : public d1, public d2 {
    public:
        d3() = default;
        d3(const base &) = delete;
        // What should I do here?
        d3(d3 &&other) : d1(std::move(other)), d2(std::move(other)) {  }
        int p;
        int q;
};

int main()
{
    d3 child;
    child.d.data = new char[1024];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
        child.d.data[i] = i * 2;
    d3 other_child = std::move(child);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
        std::cerr << other_child.d.data[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cerr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with all virtual inheritance, the virtual bases are initialized by the *most-derived* object, so:

```
d3(d3 &&other)
    : base(std::move(other)),   // <== *you* initialize the base
      d1(std::move(other)),
      d2(std::move(other)) {}
```

Comment: But... `base` is not a direct base of `d3` !

Comment: @sorush-r: Correct. It is, however, a *virtual* base. "Virutal" means "decided by the most-derived object".

Comment: Wow, what if d3 doesn't know what d1 and d2 derive from? Is this an oversight in the standard?

Comment: @RustyX statically typed language, d3 has to know or else it would not compile.

Comment: How do you handle `operator=(d3 &&other)`?

Comment: @ShacharShemesh: You either define your own operator, or use the implicit one. Note that "It is unspecified whether subobjects representing virtual base classes are assigned more than once by the
implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator."

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with asking the compiler to provide the implementation?

d3(d3 &&) = default;  // I think this the best approach as it is less error pron  .

You could write it out if you really wanted to:

d3(d3 &&other): base(std::move(other)),   d1(std::move(other)), d2(std::move(other)) 
{

}